# Regex for finding a particular sting in an ArrayList

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

I have an array list of String and I'd like to find

```
//results.getOptions() is an ArrayList<String>

Integer counter = 0;
for ( String option : results.getOptions() ) {
   System.err.println( "Item "+counter+" :"+option );
   counter++;
}
```

The output of this piece of code is:

```
Item 0 :<ET>read input: 11.844ms</ET>
Item 1 :<ET>import: 2069.9ms</ET>
Item 2 :<ET>calc: 23.022ms</ET>
Item 3 :<ET>decompress .tax: 5.451ms</ET>
Item 4 :<ET>decrypt .tax: 4.409ms</ET>
Item 5 :<ET>load .tax formsets: 7.929ms</ET>
Item 6 :<ET>There were 4 calc errors:
Item 7 :F941 0 ZIP 0 - <Error><FormCd>INWKS941</FormCd><Level>Fatal</Level><Source>Company</Source><Entity>50-7754170</Entity><Category>CompanyInfo</Category><Message>Zip code is invalid.  You must enter a valid ZIP code for your state.  Enter a correct ZIP code in this format 'nnnnn' or 'nnnnn-nnnn'.</Message></Error>.
Item 8 :F941 0 STATE 0 - <Error><FormCd>INWKS941</FormCd><Level>Fatal</Level><Source>Company</Source><Entity>50-7754170</Entity><Category>CompanyInfo</Category><Message>State abbreviation is invalid.  Enter your two-letter postal state abbreviation.</Message></Error>.
Item 9 :F941 0 L11 0 - <Error><FormCd>INWKS941</FormCd><Level>Fatal</Level><Source>Company</Source><Entity>50-7754170</Entity><Category>Calculation</Category><Message>Total taxes after adjustments does not equal the total quarter liability on Schedule B.  You must make the necessary adjustments to reconcile the amounts.</Message></Error>.
Item 10 :F941 0 L15 0 - <Error><FormCd>INWKS941</FormCd><Level>Informational</Level><Source>Company</Source><Entity>50-7754170</Entity><Category>FormInfo</Category><Message>There is a balance due on this form of $6567.78.</Message></Error>.
Item 11 :: 0.034ms</ET>
Item 12 :<ET>write FormML: 8.739ms</ET>
Item 13 :<ET>flush FormML: 0.602ms</ET>
Item 14 :<ET>copy FormML to output vector: 1.763ms</ET>
Item 15 :<ET>convert: 2147.71ms</ET>
Item 16 :<ET>write output: 0.782ms</ET>
Item 17 :<FORMSET id="FORMML"/>
Item 18 :<DATA size="247750"/>
Item 19 :<ERROR code="0"/>
Item 20 :
```

I'd like to capture the lines of text (indexes) which start with:

```
<ET>There were 4 calc errors:
```

And end with:

```
</ET>
```

(Items 6 - 11 from output)

What is the regular expression for me to capture these specific lines. I have a piece of Java code which will return me the indexes but what would the Regular expression to capture these lines be?

```
List<String> getMatchingStrings(List<String> list, String regex) {

  ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();

  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

  for (String s:list) {
    if (p.matcher(s).matches()) {
      matches.add(s);
    }
  }

  return matches
}
```

Comment: What regex have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried this: /errors[...]/</ET>/g which didn't result in anything.

Comment: Regex can't parse multiple strings from an array list at once. You need additional logic in it. Or concatenate the strings from the list to a single string and then apply the regex.

Comment: Really? But it should be able to find the indexes at which the regex matches occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a regular expression operates on a *single* string, so you have to combine you separate strings. You'd probably want to treat them as lines, so this'll work.

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (String option : results.getOptions()) {
    buf.append(option).append("\r\n");
}
```

Next, you need a regular expression that works across multiple lines, so you need the `DOTALL` option ("In dotall mode, the expression . matches any character, including a line terminator").

Also, you need the regex to be "reluctant", the opposite of "greedy", so you need `.*?`, not `.*`, and you want to capture the text between your start pattern and your end pattern, so you need a capture group `()`.

```
String regex = "<ET>There were 4 calc errors:(.*?)</ET>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(buf.toString());
while (m.find()) {
    String errorText = m.group(1);
    // Use errorText here
}
```

Of course, just in case there aren't exactly 4 errors, you might use this:

```
String regex = "<ET>There were \\d+ calc errors:(.*?)</ET>";
```

The captured text will start with newlines, so you can either `trim()` the error text, or add to the pattern.

```
String regex = "<ET>There were \\d+ calc errors:\r\n(.*?)</ET>";
```

Comment: I think I actually learned a thing or two about regex from your post, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to use regex to match each string in the list individually:

The regex `\\<ET\\>There were 4 calc errors:.*\\</ET\\>` should work. Because the special characters are escaped and the `.*` matches all characters between the tags.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, I get return an empty. I also tried on this site: http://www.regexr.com/ and 0 matches found

Comment: If you're trying to verify the regex on a website you probably need to change the \\ to \ because the \\ is just for java string escape.

Comment: I tired that: /\<ET\>There were 4 calc errors:.*\</ET\>/g

Comment: The problem is still with that site because the `/` character has special meaning. If you want to test on that site, you're going to have to put a \ in front of the /

Comment: I also tried in Java keeping the \\, are you on windows? Are backward slashes the same for mac and windows. SOrry for my noob question, I'm just trying to understand

Comment: Yes. Java strings should be the same no matter the platform

Comment: A named group is referenced by `\k<name>`, so `<` and `>` only has special meaning there.